# jquery getJSON call to cfc works on test server but not live

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I have a page that's using getJSON to access a cfc within the same domain.  Everything works fine on the development server, but not on live.  Other jquery executes fine, just not the .getJSON call.  I've tried several examples from around the web too, and using ajax instead of getJSON, but the result is always the same - fine on test, not on live.

Here is the code I'm currently using to test, which is a stripped-down version of an example at http://www.christopherchin.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/3/25/HELP-CFCjqueryJSON.

---

index.cfm:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
chkUsernameUnique = function(theUsername){
    $.getJSON("/jsonTest/mycfc.cfc", {
    method: 'chkUsername',
    Username: theUsername,
    returnformat: 'json'
    }, function(isUsernameUnique){
        $("#theErrorDivID").html(isUsernameUnique);
    });
};
</script>

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" onchange="chkUsernameUnique(this.value);" />

<div id="theErrorDivID"></div>
```

---

mycfc.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="chkUsername" access="remote" returnformat="json" output="false">
    <cfargument name="Username" required="true">

    <cfset thisRecordCount=4>

    <cfreturn thisRecordCount>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

---

Ignore the fact that it doesn't do anything useful, this is purely for testing.  On the test server, it does what it should and displays 4 if I type something in the box.  On the liver server, it doesn't actually throw an error and the browser shows that the javascript is validating, but nothing happens.  At this point I'm thinking it may be a setting on the server or in the ColdFusion admin rather than anything to do with the code, but I'm not even sure where to start with that.  Any help would be much, much appreciated.

---

Update: I see now in firebug that on the test server the response is 4.0, but on the live server it's //4.0.  What do the extra slashes mean?

Comment: which browsers have you tried this in?? also have u checked the request with fiddler and see what the responses are ??

Comment: Try to paste url directory on browser and see what exactly return as response
http://[yourdomain]/jsonTest/mycfc.cfc?method=chkUsername&username=[username]&returnformat=json

Answer (score 4):

You most likely have the "secureJson" feature of ColdFusion enabled on the live server.  What this does is secure the JSON output by putting, by default, two forward slashes in front of the JSON.  Other sources trying to access the JSON will see only a Javascript comment (//), while ColdFusion, knowing the feature is enabled, will remove the slashes and then work with it.

You can turn it off in your Application.cfc (this.secureJson = false), Application.cfm (`<cfapplication ... secureJson="false" />`) or at the function level in the cffunction tag (`<cffunction ... secureJson="false">`).  There is also a server wide setting for it in the CF Administrator.  Most likely you have this turned off in your test environment but turned on in your production environment.

Comment: Ah, you're exactly right, thanks so much!  I had no idea that was a setting.  A follow up question, then: from what I've read, using cfajaxproxy will automatically take care of removing the prefix from data that is returned, but I've been using .getJSON instead because I need to be able to perform a cross domain request.  I've read a couple of things that mention that you can remove the prefix from the jSON yourself before it's parsed if you're not using cfajaxproxy, but no explanation of how to do that.  Thoughts?

Comment: get a substring of the returned JSON minus the first two characters and use that as your JSON string.

Comment: That's the part I'm not sure about.  Do I do that before the function(isUsernameUnique) call, and how?  Any manipulation I try to do within that function never gets executed.  Thanks for any additional info.

Comment: I don't use $.getJSON, I use $.ajax for my calls, sorry. :( As a general troubleshooting rule of thumb just before the $("#theErrorDivID").html(isUsernameUnique); line I would dump out isUsernameUnique to the console.log() in Firebug and see what it returns. Assuming it's your value I don't see why you wouldn't be able to act on it.

Comment: as Rob says, instead of using getJSON use $.ajax.  You can then specify a success handler and you can manipulate the data as you like.  You would take the result returned and remove the first two characters.  You can see the docs for $.ajax here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Pam R if it was helpful, you should mark the answer as correct

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Rob and Sean; I did end up switching to $.ajax and was able to properly strip the characters.

Comment: can you show me the code you used to strip the "//" from your function?

I have the same issue.  When I get // returned my function doesn't execute and I can't even console.log the return.  But, I can successfully get a log when i remove the // from the server return.

Answer (score 0):

You have secureJSON enabled on your production CF server. Instead of turning it off on production, I would update my development server to match it, and build for it in your code. A little extra security never hurt anyone, IMO.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was indeed the problem.